# Java: Buffered Reader waiting for input before updating

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, bufferedreader

I am programming a small ChatServer program, and I've nailed down the error to this part of the client code

```
public void run() {
    Client client = new Client();
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 25555);
        client.os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while (!exit){
            String str = Input.read_string();
            client.os.writeUTF(ID+"=CLID"+str.toLowerCase());
            client.os.flush();
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
    } catch ( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `Input.read_string()` code is the following:

```
class Input{
  public static String read_string() {
    String read="";
    try {
      read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 1).readLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("error reading from the input stream!");
    }
    return read;
  }
}
```

When I put the `System.out.println(br.readLine());` at the beginning of the `while` loop the first time another client chats, but after that one has to input to get the next update.

Also, this may be fixed with the last error, but when it does update, it is the last thing the other client sent.

Comment: when you write on the client are you flushing the stream? `out.flush()`?

Comment: no, where would I do this? os is my Outputstream, the `Input` class is my only inputting code

Comment: could you post the code where you handle the output stream? reading from a socket could be a blocking call and that could be your problem. (I am just guessing)

Comment: @RaulGuiu Reading from any stream is a blocking call, but this code reads from System.in, not a socket.

Comment: @EJP but he describes it as `"ChatServer program"`, I wonder about the part that we dont see, and I guess involves sockets, as I said I am speculating.

Comment: it does indeed involve sockets, I will add the out stream above

Comment: @RaulGuiu also, it does have to do with sockets, but the system.in is what is the blocking call

Comment: @RaulGuiu I am commenting on the code he posted, which is supposed to be the topic of the question. I'm not interested in guessing about the rest of it.

Comment: @EJP, he did however I think find the error, if you see I added the OutputStream, and it turns out I think that maybe the problem, but I still don't know how to get rid of it

Comment: @user3555902 Please post server side code also.